# magento : unwanted request on all pages

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404

my magento (ver 1.7.0.2) is making an http request on /media/catalog/category/ on every pages on the website, and i want to cancel that call (which return a 404, without affecting the website, but it's the last 404 i get). I searched first on my theme, but the query still happen with default template enabled.

Comment: can you see the problem file? usually if you open `inspect element` in Chrome browser it shows you everything. `file not found` is the easiest error you can fix.

Comment: saw it on chrome, looks like sticking with opera is definitely a bad idea for web development. Some <img> tags on the top menu were broken.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the path /media/catalog/category/ usually indicates Magento is trying to load a category image. Have you checked your category images via the CMS?

EDIT: failing this it's a great idea to use firebug to troubleshoot through the code. If you browse through the HTML source you can hover your mouse over any image tags and it will show if any are missing.